# Is there a port of the Unix "wall" utility to Windows?

Tags: windows, macos

I want/need to be able to send messages to a OSX box from my Windows box.  I believe OSX includes the "wall" utility in its BSD underpinnings - is there a port of wall to Windows that will allow me to send a message over?

NOTE: I know about net send in Windows.  This is *NOT* the same thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `wall` is not a network tool, it works by writing directly to the terminal of logged-in users on a box. You cannot send messages to another box over the network anyway, so a wall port for windows does not make sense for your purposes, right?

If your next question is if there is a tool to send messages from windows to osx, generating popup windows or so - I don't know... it's probably not as simple because security aspects are to be considered.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on how it works.  It can't be done is still a valid answer for some questions ;-)